# Can I get progress messages from a submit operation?

Tags: perforce, p4api.net

I'm using Perforce's [`P4API.NET`](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/apis) to programmatically submit a large branch operation and would like to be able to provide my users with some feedback.

When using the command-line `p4` client, there's a [`-I` option](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.usingp4.html) for getting progress reports. Is there any way to get these reports with the API?

I'm using `r13.1` but can upgrade if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress reports are exposed in the C++ API via the ClientProgress class:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api/chapter.methods.html#clientuser.createprogress

This was added to the C++ API in the 2012.2 release:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4apinotes.txt

```
Major new functionality in 2012.2

    New ClientUserProgress class which shows Textual progress
    indications.  New methods in ClientUser (CreateProgress,
    and ProgressIndicator).  See api documentation for details.
```

but there is not an analogous interface yet in the .NET API.